# How to create a deffered function, that might have a ajax call inside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I am trying to chain a few AJAX calls together with $.when(func()).then(func2()).then(func3());

However, my first func() is not a straight forward AJAX call, but **CAN** have an AJAX call inside, depending on another AJAX call inside of it. Right now, my func2(), is not waiting for the func() to finish, and it's causing me issues. I feel like I'm close to the solution but can't quite get there. What am I missing here? Why is func2() not waiting for dfd.resolve()? Here is a simplified version of what I have highlighting just the problem.

```
//First in the chain...
var request = function() {
    //New Deffered....
    var dfd = new $.Deferred(),
        isPaid,
        uniqueId,
        loadUrl = '/some/url/json',
        saveUrl = '/some/other/url/';

    //First ajax call to check if our object is PAID or NOT
    $.get(loadUrl, function(data){
      isPaid = (data.isPaid === "true"),
      uniqueId =  data.latestPayNumber;
    }).done(function(){
      //If it's not paid, we'll have to create a NEW object in our database
      if(!isPaid) {
        params = [];
        params.push({ name: 'someID', value: 'value_one' });
        params.push({ name: 'someIDTwo', value: 'value_two' });
        serialisedParams = $.param(params); 
        //NOW HERE: Is another ajax call that MAY or MAY NOT happen depending on isPaid...but we have to account for it         
        $.post( saveUrl, serialisedParams)
        .done(function(data){
          //Now after this call, we have the uniqueId that we need...resolve and continue
          uniqueId = data.newUniqueId;
          dfd.resolve();
        });
      } 
      //If it was paid, we don't need to run any other ajax calls, we have our uniqueId
      else {
        parentDataBundleId = payeDataBundleId;
        dfd.resolve();        
      }                          
    });  
    return dfd.promise();                 
},
//Second in chain
chained = $.when(request()).then(function( data ) {
          //Build some params here.... and post
          return $.post( saveUrl, serialisedParams );
}),
//Third in chain
chainedTwo = chained.then(function(data){
            //Build more params......              
            return $.post( saveUrl, serialisedParams );
});

//After all calls have exectued in order, we're done...
chainedTwo.done(function( data ) {
  console.log("Weeeeee we're done!");
});
```

Comment: Your code looks good. Are you sure that the second function is executed after the `dfd.resolve()`? Could you add some debug output to the console and show us the trace? Your first function contains two asynchronous calls (second depends on `ìsPaid`). Does the problem occur when `isPaid == true` or also in the other case?

Comment: It's not clear what data is to be passed down the chain. It's important to know this because the `data` required by each stage will determine what should be returned at the previous stage.